# using regex in elasticsearch in yii2

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, yii2

i am working on Elasticsearch in yii2,i want to match a regular expression using 'regexp' in elasticsearch,my query looks like this
$result =

```
Item::find()->query([
                     'regexp' => [
                                    'item_specificattribute' =>  
                                    '\(\<[a-z]*[_]?[a-z]*>[a-z]*\<\/[a-z]*[_]?[a-z]*>,\),\<item_type>shirt\</item_type>'],])->asArray()->all();
```

my question is how do i write a regular expression to identify this expression `<item_brand>lee</item_brand>,<item_type>shirt</item_type>`

Comment: You want it to match that string or any string with <item_brand>*anystring*</item_brand>,<item_type>*anystring*</item_type>?

Comment: i want to match to string of type : <item_xxx>xyz</item_xxx>,<item_yyy>xyz</item_yyy>

Comment: I am presuming the two xyz are different? Since in your first example lee and shirt are completely different.

Comment: yes both are different values,can you help me in elasticsearch 'regexp'?

Comment: I created your regex and put it in my answer below. I have never used elasticsearch. I thought you just wanted the regular expression?

Comment: not getting any matching results,i tried using 'wildcard' in elasticsearch but still not getting results

Comment: I think I have to escape certain characters. Try new regex I put up.

Comment: 'match_phrase' in elasticsearch query helped me to get expected results,thanks for your comments and answers

Comment: Post your answer so if other people have problems, they can see what you did :)

Answer (score 0):

This will match all item brand proceeded by a comma and item types.

```
<item_([a-zA-Z]*)>[a-zA-Z]*<\/item_\1>,<item_([a-zA-Z]*)>[a-zA-Z]*<\/item_\2>
```

Escaped characters
Version 1:

```
\<item_\([a-zA-Z]*\)\>[a-zA-Z\]*\<\/item_\\1\>,\<item_\([a-zA-Z]*\)\>[a-zA-Z]*\<\/item_\\2\>
```

Shows that it works:
https://regex101.com/r/sQ5hQ2/2